# Use variable data outside of function?

Tags: javascript

I am new in programming so I am aware that you cannot use variables of a function outside of it. but I really need the object stored in 'call'. is there any workaround to extract data from it? 
I even tried to declare call outside of function but it comes back empty.

```js
function itemCollection(question, answer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answer = answer;
}

const empty = new itemCollection('empty', 'empty');
const empty2 = new itemCollection('1', '2');

function randomitem() {
  let call = itemCollection[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemCollection.length)];
}

randomitem()
console.log(call);
```

The error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: call is not defined

Comment: `call` is scoped inside `randomitem`, either you can move `console.log` into the function or make `call` global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the value:

```
function itemCollection (question, answer){
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}
const empty = new itemCollection('empty', 'empty');
const empty2 = new itemCollection('1', '2');


function randomitem() {
     return itemCollection[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemCollection.length)];
  // ^^^^^^ ---- added return keyword
}

let call = randomitem()
// ^^^^^^ ---- added variable "receiving" the value returned from the function call

console.log(call);
```

---

On a side note, since we're at it, you can profit from making the `randomitem` function pure, that is, you can pass all it needs as arguments instead of relying on `itemCollection` as a global variable:

```
function randomitem(itemCol) { // added argument; renamed to itemCol just to differentiate
     return itemCol[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemCol.length)];
}

let call = randomitem(itemCollection); // passed itemCollection as argument now

console.log(call);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D gonna study this. I am receiving 'undefined' in the console log so gonna check what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Return value from function and store returned value in a variable and use

```js
function itemCollection(question, answer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answer = answer;
}

const empty = new itemCollection('empty', 'empty');
const empty2 = new itemCollection('1', '2');

function randomitem() {
  let call = itemCollection[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemCollection.length)];
  return call
}

let call = randomitem()
console.log(call);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to return `randomitem`-s value

```
function randomitem() {
  return itemCollection[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemCollection.length)];
}

const call = randomitem();
```

Here is an arcticle about js scopes. Read this please. It is very inportant in js
https://codeburst.io/javascript-a-basic-guide-to-scope-9682d57be6fc

And also use camelcase to name your variables, functions..., like this `function randomItem() {...}`